# If GET query contains keywords from array

Tags: php, html

I want to make a PHP script that takes a PHP GET variable `$_GET[q]` made up of many different words or terms and checks to see if it contains any "keywords" that are stored in an array. An example of this would be It could look like "What time is it in San Francisco". I would want the script to pick up on "time" and "san francisco" as an example. I have played about with using

```
if(stripos($_GET[q],'keyword1','keyword2'))
```

but haven't had much luck.

**Does anyone know how I could do this?**

I hope everyone can understand what I am trying to describe.

Comment: Does `$_GET['q']` equal `keyword1`, or does it contain more characters?

Comment: Can you show us what a value for `$_GET['q']` might look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an array of keywords, then loop though until you find a match.

```
$array = array('keyword1', 'keyword2');
$found = false;
foreach($array as $x){
    if(stripos($_GET['q'], $x) !== false){
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if($found){
}
```

**UPDATE**: If you want to match *ALL* keywords, you can do this instead:

```
$array = array('keyword1', 'keyword2');
$found = true;
foreach($array as $x){
    $found &= stripos($_GET['q'], $x) !== false;
}

if($found){
}
```

DEMO: http://codepad.org/LaEX6m67

**UPDATE 2**: Because I'm crazy and like one-liners, you can do this in PHP 5.3+:

```
$array = array('keyword1', 'keyword2');
$val = $_GET['q'];
$found = array_reduce($array, function($x, $v) use($val){
    return $x && stripos($val, $v) !== false;
}, true);

if($found){
}
```

DEMO: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Y48sHR

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($arr as $value){
  if(stripos($_GET[q],$value){
    do stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function:

```
 // assuming $arr is your array of keywords
 if (in_array($_GET['q'], $arr))
     echo "found a match\n";
```

#### EDIT: Based on your comments here is the code you can use, that works without any loop:

```
$arr = array('keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3');
$brr = array_map(create_function('$m', 'return "/\b" . $m . "\b/";'), $arr);
if ($_GET['q'] !== preg_replace($brr, '', $_GET['q']))
     echo "found a match\n";
else
     echo "didn't find a match\n";
```

Comment: I think $_GET['q'] could have more characters than just the keyword.

Comment: @Jared: Sure thing but I didn't see this in OP's requirements.

Comment: @CosmoPosmo: Please add some example inputs in your question.